# Install scratchbox2 package in ubuntu 17.04/16.04

Tags: apt, dpkg

I want to install the scratchbox2 package in my 64bit Ubuntu 17.04 PC.

```
root@user-HP-EliteBook-8470p:/home/user # sudo apt-get install scratchbox2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package scratchbox2
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

From [scratchbox2](https://github.com/loganchien/scratchbox2):

- Git clone the repo:

  ```
  git clone http://git.gitorious.org/scratchbox2/scratchbox2.git
  ```
- Then,

  ```
  cd scratchbox2
  ```
- Next,

  ```
  dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot
  ```
- Finally,

  ```
  cd .. && sudo dpkg -i libsb2*deb scratchbox2*deb
  ```
- Dependencies:

  ```
  dh-make
  ```

Comment: Instructions no longer work. First, the URL is dead - but the one you're linking to for instructions works at https://github.com/loganchien/scratchbox2.git. Second, instructions on that page don't mention dh-make for Ubuntu. Finally, this happens: ../preload/system.c:28:28: fatal error: bits/libc-lock.h: No such file or directory